# Google map doesn't show perfectly after increasing width

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I use this code to increase the width and height of the google map container div:

```
var myMap = document.getElementById('googleMap');
myMap.classList.toggle('fullscreen');
```

and css:

```
.fullscreen {
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

everything work perfectly but there is a part hidden from the right side of the  map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it, Just added this within the map init function:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('resize');    
google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn, 'click', function(){resize()});

function resize(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

so when the resize button change the map's container div with css the whole map will resize too with this call